# How to rewrite this URL in php .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this URL (http://courses.net/index.php/654152?lang=en) and I want to rewrite it to a clean url (http://courses.net/englishcourse), how could I do it in my .htaccess config file?
Thanks in advance.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        RewriteRule ^englishcourse[/]?$ index.php/654152?lang=en [L,QSA]

        RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/*$ index.php/$1?&lang=$2 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: yes u are right sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/654152\?lang=en [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ /englishcourse/? [NC,L,R]

                RewriteRule ^/?englishcourse/?$ /index.php/654152?lang=en [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: It works fine on my server if i enter /index.php/6542?lang=en it redirects to /englishcourse. and if i enter /engliscourse it internally redirects to /index.php/6542?lang=en

Comment: I have this error:404 Not found.
Unable to resolve the request "englishcourse". The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: What I want is to internally when I write http://courses.net/englishcourse go to the http://courses.net/index.php/654152?lang=en but with the clean URL, if you know what I mean. I know is not very difficult but I dont use to work with regular expressions.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting the 404 , Is your htaccess in the root folder.?

Comment: Yes, the .htaccess is on the root of my www, what else it could be?

Comment: Is the mod-rewrite/htaccess enabled?

Comment: How could I check that, but I think it is enable. For example I have this rewriting module in another folder and is working, but as you can see the url format is not completely the same:   RewriteRule ^coursesparttime[/]?$ index.php?sid=32516&lang=ca [L,QSA,NC]
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/lang-([^/]*)/*$ index.php?sid=$1&lang=$2 [L,QSA]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108532/discussion-between-user2112420-and-starkeen).

Comment: To check if the mod-rewrite is enabled just put some **random texts** to your htaccess ,and then visit your site, you will get a 500 internal server Error if the htaccess is enabled

Comment: Do you have any other rules in the htaccess?

Comment: Any other rule, is empty

Comment: I can access to courses.net/index.php/654152?lang=en but when I try to access to courses.net/englishcourse show that error